# HTML5 event handling(onfocus and onfocusout) using angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a date field and I want to remove the place holder by default.

I am using javascript `onfocus` and `onfocusout` events for removing placeholder.

Can anyone help with using angular2 directive?

```html
<input name="date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')" class="dateinput">
```

I try to solving in this way, but i am getting problem with resetting the input field type.

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '.dateinput', 
    host: {
    '(focus)': 'setInputFocus()',
    '(focusout)': 'setInputFocusOut()',
  }})

  export class MyDirective {
      constructor(el: ElementRef) { this.el = el.nativeElement; console.log(this.el);}

      setInputFocus(): void {
        //console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 324, accepted):

Try to use `(focus)` and `(focusout)` instead of `onfocus` and `onfocusout`

like this : -

```html
<input name="date" type="text" (focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()">
```

also you can use like this :-

> some people prefer the on- prefix alternative, known as the canonical form:

```html
<input name="date" type="text" on-focus="focusFunction()" on-focusout="focusOutFunction()">
```

Know more about event binding [see here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding-event).

you have to use HostListner for your use case

> Angular will invoke the decorated method when the host element emits the specified event.`@HostListener` is a decorator for the callback/event handler method

See my Update working Plunker.

Working Example  <kbd>[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focusinout-event?file=src/app/app.component.html)</kbd>

## Update

Some other events can be used in angular -

```js
(focus)="myMethod()"
(blur)="myMethod()" 
(submit)="myMethod()"  
(scroll)="myMethod()"
```

Comment: where you have used your directive named as `dateinput` ?

Comment: @vishnu see my Updated plnuker

Comment: Something to note, if you use the default HTML implementation, it may use the global scope when calling the designated function. For example: `onfocusout="someMethod()"` `someMethod()`, in this case, will be called in the global scope. That's another reason why using Angular in this case is valuable.

Comment: @user5365075 I didn't see any such update, see here ng6 demo using `focus` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmphvq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: My mistake, `focus` will work on supported inputs and textareas, but if you have custom components that don't support it, you can use `focusin` instead :)

Comment: `onfocusout="myFuntion()"` does not work in angular 9 , `(focusout)="myFunction()" 
` 
Thanks @PardeepJain

Comment: @SaadAbbasi `onfocusout` should be working like `on-focusout`, for more reference please refer to a working example.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to catch the focus event dynamiclly on every input on your component :

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
       // document.getElementsByTagName('input') : to gell all Docuement imputs
       const inputList = [].slice.call((<HTMLElement>this.el.nativeElement).getElementsByTagName('input'));
        inputList.forEach((input: HTMLElement) => {
            input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
                input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'focused');
            });
            input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
                input.removeAttribute('placeholder');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Checkout the full code here :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93jdir

Answer (score 4):

I've created a little directive that bind with the tabindex attribute. It adds/removes the has-focus class dynamically.

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[tabindex]"
})
export class TabindexDirective {
    constructor(private elementHost: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener("focus")
    setInputFocus(): void {
        this.elementHost.nativeElement.classList.add("has-focus");
    }

    @HostListener("blur")
    setInputFocusOut(): void {
        this.elementHost.nativeElement.classList.remove("has-focus");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input name="date" type="text" (focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()">
```

works for me from Pardeep Jain

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
  <input (click)="focusOut()" type="text" matInput [formControl]="inputControl"
  [matAutocomplete]="auto">
   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" >
     <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="submitValue($event)" *ngFor="let option of 
      options | async" [value]="option">
      {{option.name | translate}}
     </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>

TS
focusOut() {
this.inputControl.disable();
this.inputControl.enable();
}
```