# Rewrite to angular 2 or jQuery plugins

Tags: angular

I am currently starting my first project in Angular 2, this project has multiple form elements that will interact with each other. Example below:

```
<div class="form__elem form__elem__field">
    <input class="form__elem__field__input" type="text" name="name" id="firstname">
    <div class="form__elem__field__label">
        <label for="firstname" class="form__elem__field__label__content">Your Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form__elem__field__bar">
        <div class="form__elem__field__bar--default"></div>
        <div class="form__elem__field__bar--focus"></div>
        <div class="form__elem__field__bar--danger"></div>
        <div class="form__elem__field__bar--warning"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add the class `form__elem__field__bar--default--active` to `form__elem__field__bar--default` upon focus on `form__elem__field__input`.

The form elements will also interact with other elements outside of the scope.

---

**Do I need to write these interactions using Angular 2 or is it perfectly acceptable to create a jQuery plugin that I trigger using Angular**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form__elem form__elem__field">
    <input class="form__elem__field__input" type="text" name="name" id="firstname" (focus)="focusFunction()">
    <div class="form__elem__field__label">
        <label for="firstname" class="form__elem__field__label__content">Your Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form__elem__field__bar">
        <div class="form__elem__field__bar--default" [ngClass]="{'my-class': isClassVisible }"></div>
        <div class="form__elem__field__bar--focus"></div>
        <div class="form__elem__field__bar--danger"></div>
        <div class="form__elem__field__bar--warning"></div>
    </div>
</div>


myClass:string = 'form__elem__field__bar--default';
focusFunction(){
    this.myClass = 'form__elem__field__bar--default--active';
}
```

read for more info [HTML5 event handling(onfocus and onfocusout) using angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247246/html5-event-handlingonfocus-and-onfocusout-using-angular-2)