# Angular2 - @HostListener('focus') doesn't work

Tags: angular

I'm trying to catch a focus event by @HostListener.
But it doesn't work well for me.

I saw an article below.

[HTML5 event handling(onfocus and onfocusout) using angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247246/html5-event-handlingonfocus-and-onfocusout-using-angular-2)

Also saw a plunker appeared on the article.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0K1nxX2ltZ4ztfe5uJ6E?p=preview

It worked on me.
However I changed it as below, it wouldn't work then.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<input name="date" type="text" (focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()">` 
})
export class App {
    @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target'])
    onFocus(target: any) 
        console.log("Focus called from HostListener");
        target.type = 'date';
    }
    @HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target'])
    onFocusout(target: any) {
        console.log("Focus out called from HostListener");
        target.type = 'text';
    }

    focusOutFunction(){
        console.log("Focus out called");
    }
    focusFunction(){
        console.log("Focus called");
    }
}
```

Regarding focusout, both of them are called.
But focus (focusin) works only focusFunction, not work onFocus by `@HostListener`.

How can I make `@HostListener` works with focus event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because `@HostListener` attaches a listener to the host element. In this case your host element is the `<my-app></my-app>` element. When you focus inside the `<input>` element the focus event does not bubble up to its parent. Also, only certain elements can actually fire a `focus` event and the `my-app` element is not one of them.

The example you posted uses a `@Directive` which they place on the `<input>` element. Which obviously makes it possible to listen for focus events on the directive.

You can however have a custom element fire a `(focus)` event by setting the `tabindex="0"` as attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got it. I misunderstood the role of the hostlistenler.

Comment: Directive is also the way to go, when you are working with custom components that dont expose the `(onfocus)` event

Answer (score 4):

use **blur** instead of *focusout* HostListener

`@HostListener('blur') onblur() {
.......
.......
}`

Answer (score 1):

For those desperately checking for errors in their code and finding none.

Mind that focus events are dispatched on block elements with `tabindex` set to something. This relates to both, `(event)` listeners in templates and in components via `@HostListener()`.