# Angular 2 event when input selected

Tags: angular, events

im wondering if it's in angular any event which occurs when input is selected, (select) doesn't work when I click on input by mouse(only tab)

Html:

```
<div (seeked)="setFocus($event.target.name)">
// I tried (focus) (select) (input) (click)<-this one is closest
<input type="text" name="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2">
</div
```

I work on angular 2.4.1
[edited]

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Answer (score 7):

You can use focus event of the event:

```
<input type="text" (focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()"/>
```

Check out this link:
[HTML5 event handling(onfocus and onfocusout) using angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247246/html5-event-handlingonfocus-and-onfocusout-using-angular-2)

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid using event on every inputs, but I see that I'll have too

Comment: If you have shared functionality you wanna add it to every input when it is focused you can create a directive and use it on every input.

Comment: Ye, but then I couldn't output it into other component, only to component, where it hppened

Comment: When you create directive you can import it and use it into any component. check the documentation link: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive

Answer (score 1):

You should use change event

```js
onChangeDepartment() {
    console.log("select event");
  }
```

```html
 <md-select name="department" [(ngModel)]="reportFilter.department" #departmentTemp="ngModel" (change)="onChangeDepartment()"
          required>
          <md-option *ngFor="let department of departments" [value]="department">{{department.name}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For input of text type: `(focus)="functionToCall()"`

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Angular event bindings to respond to any [DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events). Many DOM events are triggered by user input. Binding to these events provides a way to get input from the user.
>
> To bind to a DOM event, surround the DOM event name in parentheses and assign a quoted template statement to it.

```
  <input type="text" (focus)="myOnFocus($event)">
```

[source](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)

if you want to avoid binding the event to each input it would be easier/more clean to create a directive and attach it to all inputs, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342890/in-angular2-how-to-know-when-any-form-input-field-lost-focus).