# Input: display different Text when input is focused / not focues

Tags: angular

What is the easiest way to display different text inside an input depending if it is focused or not.

Example

- Focused: 150
- NotFocused: 150 €

(when accessing the value, I should get 150)

I found this answer [HTML5 event handling(onfocus and onfocusout) using angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247246/html5-event-handlingonfocus-and-onfocusout-using-angular-2). However I think there must be already a simple example, etc but I can't find it with google :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you save the input value in `amount` model, you can do the following:

```
<input  #amountInput 
        (focus)="amountInput.value = amount"  
        (focusout)="amountInput.value = currencyPipe.transform(amount,'EUR',true)" 
[(ngModel)]="amount">
```

You need to inject `CurrencyPipe` in your constructor and provide it in your component or module providers.

```
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [CurrencyPipe]
})

constructor(private currencyPipe:CurrencyPipe) { }
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgnjkx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Just barely beat me to it

Comment: @pezetter happens ;)

Comment: perfect! CurrencyPipe is a nice bonus (which I don't need because € was just an example).

Comment: Can you maybe check your demo in IE & edge too?