# Ag Grid -CellEditor FocusOut

Tags: angular, dom-events, ag-grid

I want to call `this.params.api.stopEditing();` when the CellEditor lose the focus.

**app.component.ts**

```
onFocusOut(): void {
   this.params.api.stopEditing();
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input #container triggers="" type="text" #dp="bsDatepicker" class="form-control" (bsValueChange)="onValueChange($event)" bsDatepicker 
[bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY', containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue' }"
[(ngModel)]="dateValue"
[minDate]="minDate"
[maxDate]="maxDate"
(focusOut)="onFocusOut()">
```

But focusOut is not triggered. Any idea why is not triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `(focusOut)`, it's `(focusout)`. Update your markup with that and verify.

For more references, check the answers for this post: [HTML5 event handling(onfocus and onfocusout) using angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37247490/1417185)

Comment: It works, but now I have another problem. The component is a DatePicker und has a button. When I am clicking a button on a right side inside the component, the input lose the focus. Any idea how can avoid the focusot by clicking the button?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add, at your gridOptions:

```
stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus: true
```

As you can see here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editing/#stop-editing-when-grid-loses-focus